# HINT: Perhaps you meant to reference the column

Tags: django, postgresql

When I open the page, I get error:

> column user_landings_landing.flow_chatbot_id does not exist LINE 1:
>   ...ding"."message", "user_landings_landing"."video", "user_land...
>                                                                ^ HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column
>   "user_landings_landing.flow_chatbot".

How can I fix it?

I tried `

```
SELECT "flow_chatbot" FROM user_landings_landing;
```

and

```
SELECT flow_chatbot FROM user_landings_landing;
```

but it's not inefficient. I get:

[image]

**user_landings/models**

```
class Landing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='landings',
        verbose_name=_('user')
    )
    flow_chatbot = models.ForeignKey(Flow, verbose_name=_('Flow chatbot'), blank=True, null=True)
    #other fields...
```

**user_landings_landing table**

[image]

```
f = Flow.objects.create(title='aaa', position=1)
Landing.objects.create(
    user = User.objects.first(),
    slug = 'landing',
    flow_chatbot = f
)
```

*django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "flow_chatbot_id" of relation "user_landings_landing" does not exist*

Comment: Can you share your models? What query are you running?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but it's not efficiency"?

Comment: @stickybit updated.

Comment: @pythoner: So it looks like the query is OK but there's no data in it. You can change that by, well, adding data to it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It seems there is something wrong with the structure of the table?

Comment: @stickybit tried to create `Landing` object. I got error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "flow_chatbot_id" of relation "user_landings_landing" does not exist

Comment: @stickybit updated code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table has a "flow_chatbot" column, Django is expecting the column to be "flow_chatbot_id" .  Django expects foreign key columns to end in "_id" by default.

You can use the "db_column" attribute to specify a different column name (if for example, you're trying to graft Django onto an already-existing database).